# angular ui router nested state with params cannot load stylesheet

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, angular-ui-router

I'm still new to angular ui router and I have problem with nested state / nested views need your help. 
I have angular app using ui.router with the states definition as bellow:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $stateProvider
       .state('root',{
           abstract:'true'
           views:{
                 'top@':{},
                 '@':{}
                 }
                 })
       .state('childone',{
           url:'/childone,
           parent:'root'
           views:{
                 'top':{ template:"top navigation bar"},
                  '':{template:"Main Navigation"}
                 }
            });
```

for the `childone` state, every thing work as expected until I add some params to this state like this :

```
...
.state('childone',{
   url:"/childone/:child_id",
   parent:"root",
   views:{
         'top@':{
                 template:"Top navigation with some styling in app.css"
                 }
          '@':{
                 template:"Main contain with style"
              }
         }
});
```

Now. If I navigate to this `childone` state using link (`ui-sref=({child_id:'1232'})`) the page will load all stylesheet and apply to elements ok. But if I refresh the state or go there directly using url, the page will be broken, no styles are apply to element that broke my view. I tried so many options and solution from here but nothing work for me so far. 
could someone point me out what I'm missing / wrong here please.

(
I'm trying to build a MEAN stack app. 
)

Edit: 
this is my Node/express server side to serve static index.html file:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var port = process.env.PORT||80;
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
//var passport = require('passport'); //will be used later
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cookie = require('cookie-parser');
var path = require('path');
var session = require('express-session');
var dbconf = require('./app/config/db');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var conf = require('./app/config/app');
mongoose.connect(dbconf.mongo);

/*middleware*/
app.use(cookie(conf.secret));
app.use(session({cookie: { maxAge: 60000 }}));
app.use(flash());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.use(bodyParser());
app.use(bodyParser.json({type: "application/vnd.api+json"}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));


app.get('*',function(req,res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/public/' + 'index.html'));
});

app.use(function(req,res) {
    res.status(404);
    res.send('The path not exist');
});

server.listen(port);
console.log('Http server on and serving at port ' + port);
```

Comment: I'm fairly certain (but not 100% thus a comment and not an answer) that this is actually a server redirect problem. Mean-apps actually only have one entry-point `index.html`. And all the rest urls are "fake" url changes only displayed in the browser, but for the server it should all go to the same route.  You'll need some kind of redirect (.htaccess or apache/nginx config) and point incoming requests to your "real" entrypoint (index.html). Maybe this will help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26258816/how-do-i-implement-locationprovider-html5modetrue

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#server-side from the docs. And I've seen the same CSS-less pages you are speaking about, but it was some years ago. The more I recall about it the more sure I am that this is your problem.

Comment: I have set <base href="/"> in the header of my index.html file . and my Node/express server serve static index.html as well

Comment: the request for stylesheet file return 304. not a 404. btw: how can I add image to comment here ?

Comment: Hmm, seeing your routes I *think* it uses your static resource all the time here (express uses first matching route) . Are you sure it even gets to `app.get('*',...` ?

Comment: yes, I'm sure it get there. The thing is only about applying style to the HTML element. strange thing is: only happen when I add parameters to the state url.